# Untalented girl takes long-forgotten job as guide; mayor's son talks to stones instead of trees

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

Along time ago I read a fantasy book series, I do not remember much but the main character was a girl and when she had to pick her job she was going to be a fool or something because she had no talents but was actually a long forgotten job of being a guide (or something I do not remember exactly) and the village mayor or leader's son was supposed to be able to talk to trees but was able to talk to stones instead. And there was a job called Finder or something where people found people or things.

Comment: When is "along time ago"? Do you have any idea when you might've read it? Go through [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/23384) and see if you can jog your memory.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 13):

### *The Farwalker’s Quest*

[image]

This sounds like *The Farwalker’s Quest*, by Joni Sensel.

1. *The main character had was a girl with the "long-forgotten job of being a guide."* Check. She’s a Farwalker, who used to carry news and so forth between villages.

   > When she told him, he mused, “There aren’t supposed to be any
   >   Farwalkers left. Storian told us in class that the whole trade died
   >   out.”
   >
   > “But what did they do? I couldn’t remember that part.”
   >
   > “They
   >   were guides,” Zeke replied.
   >   “Messengers, connectors. They carried news
   >   and ideas, helped people trade goods, and brought ’em together into
   >   new villages when no one could see.
2. *There’s a profession called Finder.* Check.

   > Men dug where the Finders suggested and hit water before lunchtime.
   >   That prompted talk of a hunt for sea pearls. Their success was
   >   frightening for someone like Ariel, who had never seen a Finder at
   >   work—or who didn’t want something found.
3. *The village leader’s son could talk to stones instead of trees.* Check.

   > “So are you going to be Ezekiel Stone-Singer now?” she asked.
   >
   > “I don’t know. I guess so. Does it sound crazy?”
   >
   > “Yes. I never heard of a Stone-Singer. Tree-singing is weird enough.”

Answer (score 4):

It could also be ***So You Want to Be a Wizard***, though it seems less likely.

[image: So You Want to Be a Wizard cover]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e2/Sywbaw_cover.jpg/220px-Sywbaw_cover.jpg))</sub>

Key points:

> The main character was a girl

Check.  The main character is a girl named Nita Callahan.

> The leader's son was supposed to talk to trees but can talk to stones instead.

Sort of check. Nita can talk to trees, and she meets a boy named Kit Rodriguez who can talk to stones.  Each initially finds the other's ability odd.